# Giving only-Webi permissions to user

Tags: permissions, business-objects, webi

I wanna restrict user right only to webi, when viewing report in a Webi he will just play with the sliders and export that report as an Excel file locally.

But he shouldn't be able to save the file in any way just view it.

Thanks and regards,

gaurav

Answer (score 1):

View on Demand. User is able to Save report as excel file. But not able to Edit/Save.